# Using two authentication types in SmartGit or PhpStorm

Tags: git, ssh, phpstorm, smartgit

I have a git repo at a shared webhost that uses "password,publickey" for ssh authentication. In both PhpStorm and SmartGit I can only chose *either* key pair or password authentication methods when I try to push commits to the git repo.

It will sometimes prompt me to type in a password but that never works, however when i push through the terminal in PhpStorm it's working fine. I can use the terminal but I would rather use the GUI that PhpStorm or SmartGit offers.

Is there some way to authenticate with both methods? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you prompted for your account password or for the passphrase which is protecting your private key?

Comment: If I choose the keypair auth type it will prompt me for the account password, which seems logic. But it just won't accept my password - it keeps prompting me with authentication failed.
If I do it in the terminal it will also prompt me for the password and that works fine.

Comment: In case of public key authentication, you should be prompted for *certificate* and *passphrase*. You may check `log.txt` in the settings directory (see About dialog) whether it contains additional details on what went wrong with the SSH authentication.